# The value of input element changes but not shown in the browser(s)?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, livesearch

I wrote a live search field for a part of my form, when the suggestions come and user clicks on one of them, a `js` function (`selectedService`) is being called to get the `innerHTML` of the `li` which the user clicked on!
everything works perfectly when you look at the code in 'Inspect Element' of the browser, but not on the web page!

after the user clicks on the on the suggestion the value property of input element changes in the code but on the browser. the content of input field is still what the user is typing in it.

here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<input value="" id="services" placeholder="click or type plz..."/>
<ul id="suggestions">
</ul>
<style>
    /* some styles */
</style>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("services");
var suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

input.oninput = function() {
    var q = input.value;

    if (q.length < 2) {
        suggestions.setAttribute("style","display: none");
        return;
    }
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr2.open("GET", "theURL/service-request-handler.php?q="+q, true);
    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200)
        {
            var result = xhr2.responseText;
            console.log("server response = "+result);
            var json = JSON.parse(result);
            showSuggestions(json);
        }
    };
    xhr2.send();
};

function showSuggestions(json) {
    suggestions.setAttribute("style","display: block");
    var li_list = '';
    var i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<json.length; i++) 
        li_list += '<li id="'+i+'" onclick="selectedService('+i+')">'+json[i]+'</li>';

    suggestions.innerHTML = li_list;
}

function selectedService(i) {
    li_target = document.getElementById(i);
    console.log(li_target.innerHTML);
//    input.innerHTML = li_target.innerHTML;
    input.setAttribute("value",li_target.innerHTML);
    suggestions.setAttribute("style","display: none");
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the result in the Inspect Element : 
[image: before onclick event]

[image: when event happens!]

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions :)

Comment: function selectedService(i) {
    li_target = document.getElementById(i);
    console.log(li_target.innerHTML);
//    input.innerHTML = li_target.innerHTML;
    input.setAttribute("textContent",li_target.innerHTML);
    suggestions.setAttribute("style","display: none");
}
 Can you try this

Comment: @Suresh instead of the value property, the clicked option goes after the tag.
like this :

<input value=""/>selected option ... still nothing to the use :(

Comment: can i get any jsfiddle link?

Comment: what is happening when you tried   input.value = li_target.innerHTML;

Comment: @Suresh I can but what about the `php` script ?! I haven't tried it.. I'll do it now!

Comment: @Suresh input.value worked like a charm! tnx

Comment: :) posted answer in answer section..

Comment: @Suresh it's upvoted ;)) tnx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.value = li_target.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `value` property directly:

```js
input.value=li_target.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using firefox browser, you should use this to work in both, chrome and firefox.

`input.value = li_target.innerHTML;`

This happens because property and attributes are different.

Attributes are defined on the HTML markup but properties are defined on the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery UI for autocomplete search.

Comment: can't do...
I gotta use pure `js`